# ios15 Safari- disable opening tab bar on double tap

Tags: javascript, safari, tabbar, ios15

How I can prevent opening of tab bar every time user double clicks on my web page on new ios 15 safari in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prevent the floating address bar from popping up on tap or swipe is to use `preventDefault()` on touch / mouse events. I have found this is working for me on iOS 15 Beta 4 when dealing with a `canvas` taking up the full screen:

```
const preventDefault = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault()
}

// Make sure to remove these event listeners later.
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault)
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', preventDefault)
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', preventDefault)
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault)
```

If you don't have a `canvas` you'll instead want to attach it to a different full screen DOM element. In my testing I found some issues with using `document` or `body`, so you may need to do some work & testing to determine what works and is safe to use (i.e. doesn't prevent `button`'s from working).